# Target or Subject of a Requirement or Criteria

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What would be a good term for the subject of a *requirement*? If one has a requirement applied to them, they would be the *[word]* of that requirement. I'm looking for something more descriptive than *subject* or *target*. *Constrained* seems like a good fit, but it feels a bit unwieldy?

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, the set of {things that satisfy the equation} is called the *solution set*.

Comment: That would work well for subjects that met the requirement, but would it still apply to those whose status are unknown? So they are supposed to meet the requirement, but we don't know yet whether or not that is true. Maybe a _predicate_?